# COmo subir datos a la red desde una un programa de escritorio desarrollado en visual studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

Tengo un programa desarrollado en visual studio(windows form) con base datos en sql-server 2012 y quiero saber si puedo subir esos datos a una pagina web o sitio en la red.

Comment: Hola @Daniel, bienvenido! La respuesta es sí. El *cómo* va a depender de a dónde quieras subirlo, de qué manera y qué hayas intentado hasta ahora. La pregunta es un poco amplia ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta e intentar reducirla a algo más específico? Por favor lee [mcve].

Comment: Es mi primera vez que intentaria hacer esto, tomare en cuenta las lecturas, y mas o menos pretendo subirlo a una pagina web para que todos puedan ver los datos almacenados en la aplicacion de escritorio, gracias !!!

Comment: En qué plataforma está desarrollado el sitio web?

Comment: Buenos días Daniel, sí tienes una base de datos, entonces por que no haces consulta a la misma desde la aplicación web. O necesariamente ocupas que la información venga desde la aplicación?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la Clase **WebClient**, que proporciona métodos comunes para enviar datos a o recibir datos desde cualquier local, intranet o recurso de Internet identificado por un URI.

Esta clase la utilizarías en tu aplicación de Window y por medio de esta se comunicaría con la aplicación Web, esta ultima deberá implementar un Web Service o servicios REST.